# C program to print given number of lines from beginning of text file. File name and number of lines from command line argument

Tags: c

I'm writing a program said in this post title. I take reference at this webpage.

https://www.includehelp.com/c-programs/c-program-to-print-given-number-of-lines-of-a-file-like-head-command-in-linux.aspx

Here are the codes from that webpage.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;             // file pointer
    char *line = NULL;
    int len = 0;
 
    int cnt = 0;    
 
    if( argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Insufficient Arguments!!!\n");
        printf("Please use \"program-name file-name N\" format.\n");
        return -1;
    }
 
    // open file
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
 
    // checking for file is exist or not
    if( fp == NULL )
    {
        printf("\n%s file can not be opened !!!\n",argv[1]);
        return 1;   
    }
 
    // read lines from file one by one
    while (getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1)
    {
        cnt++;
        if ( cnt > atoi(argv[2]) )
            break;
 
        printf("%s",line); fflush(stdout);
    }
     
    // close file
    fclose(fp);
 
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is the getline function. Since I'm not using Linux that function's giving error in my compiler. I tried to change it to fgets function. This is my revised codes.

I got two errors in the line ' while (fgets(&line, bufferLength, fp) != -1)'.
Error: passing argument 1 of 'fgets' from incompatible pointer type.
Error: comparison between pointer and integer.

My question is - how can I modify the program using fgets? Many thanks to anyone who can work this out.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;             // file pointer
    char *line = NULL;
    int bufferLength = 255;
    int cnt = 0;

    if( argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Insufficient Arguments!!!\n");
        printf("Please use \"program-name file-name N\" format.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // open file
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");

    // checking for file is exist or not
    if( fp == NULL )
    {
        printf("\n%s file can not be opened !!!\n",argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    // read lines from file one by one
    while (fgets(&line, bufferLength, fp) != -1)
    {
        cnt++;
        if ( cnt > atoi(argv[2]) )
            break;

        printf("%s",line);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    // close file
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must use `while (fgets(line, bufferLength, fp) != NULL)`. But before that, you must allocate space for the `line`.

Comment: This is not a job for either fgets or getline.  You only need to read one character at a time, not whole lines.  Read a char, print it.  If it's a newline, increment a counter.  If the counter is N, exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program should compile and run correctly follows:

```
//c program to print given number of lines from beginning of a file
//file name and number of lines must be supply as command line argument

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE* fp;             // file pointer
    char* line = malloc(255);
    int bufferLength = 255;

    int cnt = 0;

    if( argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Insufficient Arguments!!!\n");
        printf("Please use \"program-name file-name N\" format.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // open file
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");

    // checking for file is exist or not
    if( fp == NULL )
    {
        printf("\n%s file can not be opened !!!\n",argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    // read lines from file one by one
    while (fgets(line,bufferLength, fp))
    {
        cnt++;
        if ( cnt > atoi(argv[2]) )
            break;

        printf("%s",line); 
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    // close file
    fclose(fp);
    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

we have two main problems, first
char * line = NULL;
line is a line of characters, a string if you want to call it that, so we must reserve enough memory to accommodate a complete line, and we do this with the malloc function, as seen in the program, the other problem we have with fgets, this function returns a pointer therefore we cannot compare the value returned by fgets with an integer, the declaration

```
 while (fgets (line, bufferLength, fp))
```

is equivalent to running the loop while fgets is other than NULL. Finally we must use **line** instead of **&line**, the latter asks for the address of the line pointer, and not the address it points to.

Comment: OK, I just ran out of time for more

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to keep track of more than a single character.  Reading full lines is overkill.  Just do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
        FILE *fp = fopen(path, mode);
        if( fp == NULL ) {
                perror(path);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return fp;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int count = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 1;
        FILE *in = argc > 2 ? xfopen(argv[2], "r") : stdin;
        int line = 0;
        int c;
        while( line < count && ( c = fgetc(in)) != EOF ) {
                putchar(c);
                if( c == '\n' ) {
                        line += 1;
                }
        }
}
```

Note that I've reversed the order of the arguments, so that stdin is read if only a count is given.